# Searching in nested arrays for empty object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var array = [
  {
    key: 'value',
    subArray: [{ key: 'value', subArray: [{}] }]
  },
  {
    key: 'value',
    subArray: [{ key: 'value', subArray: [{ key: 'value', subArray: [] }] }]
  },
  { key: 'value', subArray: [] }
];
```

In my application I've got array of objects. Each objects have field containing another array which can contain another object with field containing array and so on. In some cases objects could be empty. I need write function which will be iterate over all arrays, finds emty objects and remove them. How can I achive this?

Comment: Can you please share your effort and desired output?

Comment: what is an empty object?

Comment: You can use DFS algorithm here. 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/depth-first-search-or-dfs-for-a-graph/

Comment: In fact, I'm trying to build some form builder. In application user cad add some inputs. Each inputs can have subInputs. This varriable that I show above is containing current state of builded form. Empty subArray means that inputs has no subInputs. If subArray contains empty Object that means that inputs had subInputs but subInputs was deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution is to use recursion.

```js
var array = [
  {
    key: 'value',
    subArray: [{ key: 'value', subArray: [{}] }]
  },
  {
    key: 'value',
    subArray: [{ key: 'value', subArray: [{ key: 'value', subArray: [] }] }]
  },
  { key: 'value', subArray: [] }
];


function lookup(subArr) {
    subArr.forEach((sa, i) => {
        if (Object.keys(sa).length == 0) {
           delete subArr[i];
        } else {
           lookup(sa.subArray);
        }
    });
}


array.forEach(a => {
    lookup(a.subArray);
});


console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
  if (array[i].subArray.length != 0) {
    if (Object.keys(array[i].subArray).length)) {
      delete Object.keys(array[i].subArray
    }
  }
}
```

may be useful for you

Comment: This isn't recursive so will only work for a certain depth, also it seems you are deleting arrays that have length which is the opposite of what OP is trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. Hope it will help to figure out the solution :

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ){
    if(array[i].subArray)
    {
        removeEmptyItems(array[i].subArray);
    } 
}

removeEmptyItems(item: any) {
    if(item.length == 0){
        delete item;
        return;
    }
    if (item.subArray) {            
        removeEmptyItems(item.subArray);
    } 
}
```

Comment: When You are calling removeEmptyItems You are give it subArray as argument.  Thats ok. But then You are checking if its length is equal 0 thats means You are checking if subArray is empty and then if is delete subArr. Thats not what i woudl like to achive. I need check if subArray contains empty object. SubArray can contains infinitive number of objects. I need detect if some of this objects are empty: {} and then a need delete only this empty objects from array, not whole array.

Comment: Well, i just wanted to share my idea. You need to modify this :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find empty objects and remove them (in other words, turn `subArray: [{}]` to `subArray: []`), then you can do it with recursive function that replaces all occurrences of arrays with one empty object with an empty arrays:

```
var array = [
  {
    key: 'value',
    subArray: [{ key: 'value', subArray: [{}] }]
  },
  {
    key: 'value',
    subArray: [{ key: 'value', subArray: [{ key: 'value', subArray: [] }] }]
  },
  { key: 'value', subArray: [] }
];

function removeEmptyObjects(obj) {

    var objCopy = Object.assign({}, obj);

    Object.keys(objCopy).forEach(key => {

        if (!Array.isArray(objCopy[key])) return;

        var containsEmptyObject = objCopy[key].length === 1 && typeof objCopy[key][0] === 'object' && Object.keys(objCopy[key][0]).length === 0;

        objCopy[key] = containsEmptyObject ? [] : objCopy[key].map(removeEmptyObjects);

    });

    return objCopy;

}

var result = array.map(removeEmptyObjects);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```